# Child objects in jQuery - how to select in a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

it's sounds basic...I've this...

```
    <div id="carouselBrand">
        <div class="carouselSelectorLeft">O</div>
        <div class="carouselWrapper">
            <div class="carouselSelector">
                <div class="carouselItems">
                <img src="./images/dell.png" alt="">
                <img src="./images/dell.png" alt="">
                <img src="./images/dell.png" alt="">
                <img src="./images/dell.png" alt="">
                <img src="./images/dell.png" alt="">
                <img src="./images/dell.png" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carouselSelectorRight">O</div>
    </div>
```

I want to bound a click event...

```
    $(".carouselSelectorRight").click(function() {

    });
```

I need to select the carouselSelector, so basically: get the 1st div with class carouselSelector inside the parent of my object that's handle the click.

It's supposed to be something like this...

```
    var select = $(event.target).parent.$('.carouselSelector');
```

But this is not the correct way...any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways for selecting the target element:

```
$(".carouselSelectorRight").click(function() {
    var select = $(this).prev().children('.carouselSelector');
});
```

You can also use the `closest`/`parent` and `find` methods:

```
$(this).closest('.carouselBrand').find('.carouselSelector');
```

If the parent `.carouselBrand` element have more than 1 `.carouselSelector` descendant and you want to select the `first` one of them, you can use the `first` method:

```
select.first(); // where select is the returned collection by above queries
```

Note that if you want to use the `event` object you should pass it to your event handler:

```
$(".carouselSelectorRight").click(function(event) {
```